# How to set image name with comma in to the hiddenfeild?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set hidden field value as comma separated image name from input type file control. I have tried using jQuery,

```js
var idProjectTitle = document.getElementsByClassName("idProjectTitle");

           
           var path2 = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < idProjectTitle.length; i++) {
          
                path2 += idProjectTitle[i].files[0].name + ',';              
        }
            $('#hdProjectTitle').val(path2); /*Here is setting image names as hdfield value*/
```

But error occurring 'cannot read property 'name' of undefined'. How can I solve this ?

Comment: try to post a question completely. we'll need your html too

Comment: It means, your file control doesnt have a file. idProjectTitle[some value].files[0] is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It should solve, if you want to add only existing files.

```js
    $('.idProjectTitle').change(function(){

    var idProjectTitle = document.getElementsByClassName("idProjectTitle");

               
               var path2 = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < idProjectTitle.length; i++) {
              if(idProjectTitle[i].files[0] != undefined){
                    path2 += idProjectTitle[i].files[0].name + ',';              
}
            }
                $('#hdProjectTitle').val(path2); /*Here is setting image names as hdfield value*/
            
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="file" multiple class="idProjectTitle" />

<input type="text" id="hdProjectTitle" name="hdProjectTitle" />
```

Comment: i think it just copy of my answer

Comment: I didn't give this line of code ' if(idProjectTitle[i].files[0] != undefined)' , that was the error cause. thanks

Comment: @JYoThI Nope. You can check the posted minutes.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do this in  `file input on change` function inside like this

```js
$('.idProjectTitle').change(function(){

var idProjectTitle = document.getElementsByClassName("idProjectTitle");

           
           var path2 = "";
           for (var i = 0; i < idProjectTitle.length; i++) 
           {

               if(idProjectTitle[i].files[0] != undefined)
               {
                  path2 += idProjectTitle[i].files[0].name + ',';  

                }            
            }

            $('#hdProjectTitle').val(path2);
            
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="file" multiple class="idProjectTitle" />

<input type="text" id="hdProjectTitle" name="hdProjectTitle" />
```